# Prove that this space is compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally compact connected complete metric space with metric $d_X$. Suppose that $K$ is compact in $X$. I want to show the following: for any $0<\delta\in \mathbb{R}$, the set $$K+\delta=\{p\in X: d_X(p,K)\le \delta\}$$
is compact.

This set is clearly closed, my thinking is that maybe we can show it's totally bounded. I think locally compactness should play a key role here, but I don't know how to use that.

Thanks

Comment: Notice that the bounded metric $$ \rho(x, y) = \min\{ |x - y|, 1\} $$ on $\Bbb{R}$ induces the standard topology. In particular, this shows that $(\Bbb{R}, \rho)$ is locally compact and connected. It is also easy to check that $(\Bbb{R}, \rho)$ is complete. Then for any non-empty compact subset $K \subset \Bbb{R}$ and for any $\delta \geq 1$, we have $K + \delta = \Bbb{R}$, which is not compact.

Comment: Thanks Lee! I really appreciate it! If you have time, could you please also take a look at this problem? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179494/is-this-sequence-relatively-compact