# Is this sequence relatively compact?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $M$ be a locally compact connected complete metric space with metric $d$. Define $\mathcal{F}$ to be the family of continuous, distance decreasing mappings from $M$ to itself with the property that $f(p)=p$ for some $p\in M$. Now let's fix $q\in M$ where $q\neq p$ and pick $\{f_n\}$ any sequence in $\mathcal{F}$.

My question is: does this sequence $\{f_n(q)\}$ has a convergent subsequence?

Any comments or counter-examples are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind checking if I am understanding the setting correctly? (1) does 'distance-decreasing' mean that $d(f(p), f(q)) \leq d(p, q)$? (2) Does the choice of fixed point depend on $f \in \mathcal{F}$? Or is it assumes that you can pick a single $p\in M$ for which $f(p) = p$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: For your first question, yes. The second one: we fix point p first and then consider the family F depends on p. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I got so far: If we impose a so called 'inner' metric condition on $M$, then we would be able to conclude that any closed bounded ball are compact.

Roughly speaking, the inner metric condition would rule out the cases where two points are close in distance but can be connected by a 'longer' curve. For instance, in Lee's example: $\mathbb{R}$ with bounded metric $d(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1\}$: $d(0,10)=1$, but they can be connected by a line segment with 'length' $10$. Namely, 10 pieces of intervals with length $1$.

Here, I did not define the length rigorously, details can be found in Kobayshi's book Hyperbolic Complex Spaces, Page 1-5.